# Date Format in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, dataset

I have datetime column in sql server and its 24hr format. But when I execute the query to fetch the data and store that in a dataset its showing 12hr format. I need the same format as in database.

Please help.

Comment: Check this for SQL date formats - http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: I am able to use 'select *' only not using any formatting in query

Answer (score 2):

In Global.asax

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

//...

protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
  CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo) System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
  newCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
 newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
}
```

Comment: Its not possible to do for specific column I need to do for many number of columns in same dataset.

Comment: @Saritha.S.R Edited my answer. Please try

Comment: use this method with caution this will change the behaviour of your datetime in whole site.+1 for simple and compact answer.

Answer (score 0):

values in a datetime column are stored as number of days since 01.01.1900 (4 byte) and number of clock ticks since midnight (4 bytes) ... it has nothing to do with 24hr/12hr format ... that is just a matter of what you do with the date values (affected by regional settings etc) ...